# Creating identical 'copies' of circuit elements?

Tags: circuit-design, potentiometer

I have a circuit comprising of 3 identical nodes connected in a loop i.e. output of 1st node is input of 2nd, output of 2nd is input of 3rd, and output of 3rd is input of 1st. Circuit diagram of the node is below.

Now, each node has a potentiometer which I wish to vary (\$R_3\$ in the circuit diagram). As all 3 nodes are identical, I need to vary all 3 potentiometers identically. However practically, this is, of course, unfeasible to do by hand.

So, is there any way I can only use 1 potentiometer, and redesign the circuit such that I effectively get 3 'copies' of the potentiometer, with 1 in each node? If so, then I could effectively vary all 3 of them identically.

[image]

Comment: Get a triple pot on a single shaft, then you don't have to touch the schematic.

Answer (score 2):

You would be using the pot as a variable resistor aka rheostat.

You could use 3 potentimeters with the wipers mechanically connected (a ganged pot). Eg. from [here](http://www.potentiometers.com/PTD90.cfm)

[image]

Or you may be able to use digital pots.

Comment: Bourns still sell stackables? Good to know.